# Calling controller action from KENDO UI Grid Control using template definition

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have a KENDO Grid and the fields and columns in that are populated from a datasource which is intern populated from an action.

Now i want to bind a particular cell content in that grid to another controller action and pass that ID of the cell also. How do I accomplish this. Below is the code for my grid. I could find answers in kendo UI docs but they use HTML Helpers to achieve this. I want it in the same style as below. Let us take the readername as the cell content for which this binding is required. Anybody tried this before?

```
$("#eventsgrid").kendoGrid(
                            {
                                dataSource: eventsDataSource,
                            navigatable: true,
                            pageable:
                                {
                                input: true,
                                numeric: false
                                },

                            columns:[
                            {
                                field:"",width:"30px", template:'<input type="checkbox" id="selectevent"/>'
                            },
                            {
                                field:"CardNumber",width:"80px"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Image", width: "45px", title: "Type", template: "<img src='/Content/Themes/Default/images/AlarmType.png' id='AlarmType'/>"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Priority", width: "60px", title: "Priroty"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Origin", title:"Event Time"
                            },
                            {
                                field:"Description", title:"Alarm Title"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "ReaderName", title: "Location"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "", title: "Actions and Interactions", width: "160px", template: '<input type="button" value="Acknowledge" onclick="CheckAck" id="Acknowledge" /><br/><a href="javascript:performActions()"  >3 Actions</a>'
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Image", title: "More", width: "60px", template: "<img src='/Content/Themes/Default/images/Door.png' onclick='showDetails()' id='door' width='20' height='20'/><div id='cardholderdetails'></div>"
                            }

                            ],

                        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

**Now i have a function which calls a $.POST call with the parameters. This function is hooked to the click event of the button. Is there a different way to do this?**

Comment: Have you actually tried something?

Comment: Yet to try. Was stuck with another activity.

Comment: Now i have a function which calls a $.POST call with the parameters. This function is hooked to the click event of the button. Is there  a different way to do this.